# I am trying to convert a 12 hour time format to 24 hour time format ,and store it in a string but i am not able to store it in a string

Tags: c++, string

So this is my function name converter which returns the new string. But I don't know how to store this thing in the string. Please help me why I am getting compilation error.
Strcpy is not working . And how do I store the variable hh in my string?

```
    string converter(string str)
    {
        string newstring;  /// Creating a new string which I return from here
        int h1 = (int)str[1] - '0';
        int h2 = (int)str[0] - '0';
        int hh = (h2 * 10 + h1 % 10);
    
        // If time is in "AM"
        if (str[5] == 'A')
        {
            if (hh == 12)
            {
                string stringone("00");
         strcpy(newstring,stringone);         //getting error caanot convert
                for (int i=2; i < 5;i++)
                    newstring[i]=str[i];
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i=0; i < 5; i++)
                    newstring[i]=str[i]; 
            }
        }
    
        // If time is in "PM"
        else
        {
            if (hh == 12)
            {
                char stringtwo="12";
                strcpy(newstring,stringtwo);
                for (int i=2; i < 5; i++)
                   newstring[i]=str[i];
            }
            else
            {
                hh = hh + 12;
                newstring.push_back(hh);  /// Is this correct?
             
                for (int i=2;i < 5;i++)
                    newstring[i]=str[i];
            }
        }
return newstring;
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the [man page for strcpy](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy)? "string" in C, 1978 has a different meaning than "string" in C++, 1985. Read the documentation (for std::string e.g.https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and pay attention to argument and return types.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

//converts time in hh:mm am/pm string format & string length should be 8 for function to work properly
std::string converter(std::string str){
    std::string newstring;
    std::string amOrpm = {str.at(6), str.at(7)};
    char hr[2] = {str.at(0), str.at(1)};
    int hour = atoi(hr);
    
    //if time is pm convert to 24hr format
    if(amOrpm == "pm"){
        hour += 12;
        newstring = std::to_string(hour);
        for(int i = 0; i < newstring.length(); i++)
            str.at(i) = newstring.at(i);
        
        for(int i = 6; i < str.length(); i++)
            str.at(i) = NULL;
        return str;
    }else
        return str;
}
```

Comment: you can add a few lines of code to the function to make sure the length of the string is always 8

Comment: Thanks i will try this